# Access Denied Error for user 'root'@'***.***.***.***'

Tags: c#, mysql, .net

Error: `dotnet mysql connection Access denied for user 'root'@'***.***.***.***'`

I got this error when I use MySqlConnection to connect to a mysql server. I put in the correct user name and password, and I can use `phpmyadmin` to log in the server with the username and password.

Also, there is a line with root and `%` in the privileges page. Is there anything else that I don't know that could make this error?

Comment: Does the server allow remote connections?

Comment: You might what to post some of your code as well as the error that it generates?

Comment: connstr = "server=serverip; User id=root; pwd=password; Database=database";

            MySqlConnection myconn = new MySqlConnection(connstr);

            try
            {
                myconn.Open();
            }
            catch (MySqlException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                return;
            }  -- code

Comment: Access denied for user 'root'@'serverip' (using password: YES) -- error message

Comment: I can use phpmyadmin to log in the mysql server

Answer (score 0):

Better if you show your code.
Try to craete a new user like:

```
CREATE USER 'test_user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'some_pass';
```

Then grant all PRIVILEGES ON shop:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON shop.* TO 'test_user'@'localhost';
```

Try to connect via this user. May be it is due to PRIVILEGES issue.